# Store elememts of a datatable into an array

Tags: php, sql

I have a database table made in phpmyadmin. I want the elements of the table to be stored row-wise in an array. I have three columns named `edge_id`, `vertexA` and `VertexB`. I want the elements of these three columns to be stored into an array.

I don't know those commands for PHP. Please help me out.

Comment: pleas give a full example of what your are trying to accomplish. Do you mean the mysql `table` or an html `<table>`? And are you talking about puting the contents of the db inot an html table or printing the contents of a db query in an html table structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i have columns in my table named
>   "vertexa" and "vertexb",i want to
>   store the colums in two separate
>   arrays ...how can i do it??

The simplest way would be:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=your_db_name;', $user, $password);
$vertices_a = array();
$vertices_b = array();

foreach($db->query('SELECT * from your_table_name') as $row){
  $id = $row['edge_id'];

  // add them to the proper array using the edge_id as the index - 
  // this assumes edge_id is unique
  $vertices_a[$id] = $row['vertexa'];
  $vertices_b[$id] $row['vertexb'];
}
```

---

So with PDO:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=your_db_name;', $user, $password);

foreach($db->query('SELECT * from your_table_name') as $row){
  echo $row['edge_id'];
  echo $row['vertexA'];
  echo $row['vertexB'];
}
```

Now if you need to use input data you need to escape it. The best way to do this is to use a prepared statement because  escaping is handle when the parameters are bound to the query.

Lets say for example you want to use the `edge_id` supplied from a get request like `mysite.com/show-boundry.php?edge=5`...

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=your_db_name;', $user, $password);

// create a prepared statement
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * from your_table_name WHERE edge_id = ?');

// execute the statement binding the edge_id request parameter to the prepared query
$stmt->execute(array($_GET['edge']));

// loop through the results    
while(false !== ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))){
  echo $row['edge_id'];
  echo $row['vertexA'];
  echo $row['vertexB'];
}
```

Also you shouldnt use mixed case column/table names like `vertexA` instead use underscore separators like `vertex_a`.

Comment: i have columns in my table named "vertexa" and "vertexb",i want to store the colums in two separate arrays ...how can i do it??

Comment: see my update, but really i would encourage you do jsut read the PDO documentation and maybe seek out some "gettign started" type tutorials like: http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html or http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/

Comment: Dont forget to select an answer to your question! ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You first need to connect to the database:

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost','username','password');
if (!$link) {
    // Cannot connect
}
$ret = mysql_select_db('database-name', $link);
if (!$ret) {
    // Cannot select database
}
```

Then you need to execute your query:

```
$ret = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `table`;', $link);
if (!$ret) {
    // Query failed
}
```

Then you simply load each row:

```
$data = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($ret)) {
    $data[] = $row;
}
```

Then you should free your request results

```
mysql_free_result($ret);
```

And voilà.

Comment: Only dont use the `mysql` extension. use `PDO` or `mysqli`... preferably PDO.

Answer (score 1):

```
$res = mysql_query("............");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($res);
```

Checkout: [mysql_fetch_array PHP page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)